# WP_Query to get posts with featured image OR video format posts without featured image

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently working on a query where I show only posts without empty featured image using this:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id')
    )
);
```

Everything is working great. But I have some video format posts without featured images that I would like to return with that query.

Is that even possible with WP_Query?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work with 2 WP_Query and a array_merge, not sure if it's the best way to go but does the work.

If that can help:

*get posts with thumb*

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id'), //Show only posts with featured images
    )
);
$posts_with_thumb = new WP_Query($args);
```

*get video posts format*

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'post-format-video' ),
        ),
    )
);
$posts_video_format = new WP_Query($args);
```

*init new wp_query object and merge both results*

```
$featured_query = new WP_Query();
$featured_query->posts = array_merge( $posts_with_thumb->posts, $posts_video_format->posts );
```